# plotly, half polar chart, setting angular axis from -90° to 90°

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

I'm trying to plot a polar chart with python and plotly to show the orientation of fibers in an 2D image (see the code below).
It would be great if you could show me how to change the angular axis, currently ranging from 0° to 360°, to match my data ranging from -90° to 90°. 
Below are example images of a half polar chart, the format of my data, and my code.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import plotly
import plotly.offline as offline
import numpy as np

# data
x= np.genfromtxt(see data image) 
y= np.genfromtxt(see data image)

trace = [
    go.Scatterpolar(
        r = [y], #radial coordinates
        theta = [x], #angular coordinates
        mode = 'markers',
        marker = dict(
            color = 'peru'
        )
    )
]

layout = go.Layout(
    showlegend = True,
    polar = dict(
        domain = dict( # set chart size and position 
        x = [0, 0.8],
        y = [0.3, 0.8]),
        sector = [0, 180],   # set chart shape (half or full)
        angularaxis = dict(
            thetaunit = "degrees",
            dtick = 10),
        radialaxis = dict(
            range = [1, 8000])      
))


fig = go.Figure(data=trace, layout=layout)
offline.plot(fig)
```

[image: data image]
<sup>**x-y data**</sup>

[image: half polar chart for fiber orientation]
<sup>**half polar chart for fiber orientation**</sup>

Comment: Not sure if `ScatterPolar` has the same configuration options, but check the answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863268/change-axis-of-plotly-polar-plot) to see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you. I've seen this and it doesn't work in this case. (ValueError: Invalid property specified for object of type plotly.graph_objs.layout.polar.AngularAxis: 'range').

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I only got output by making the following changes:

- Changed the `go.Layout` `sector=[0, 180]` to `sector=[-90, 90]`
- Changed the `go.Scatterplot` `r=[y]` to `r=[float(a) for a in y]`
- Changed the `go.Scatterplot` `theta=[x]` to `theta=[float(b) for b in x]`

The first change created the range that you require (-90 to 90)

The 2nd and 3rd changes converted the results from `np.genfromtext()` from strings to numeric (although these changes may not be necessary if your data is already numerical within `x` and `y`).

My code now looks like this:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as offline
import numpy as np

# data
x = np.genfromtxt([str(i) for i in range(-90, 91)])
y = np.genfromtxt([str(i * 25 + np.random.randint(1000, 2500)) for i in range(0, 181)])

trace = [
    go.Scatterpolar(
        r=[float(a) for a in y],  # radial coordinates
        theta=[float(b) for b in x],  # angular coordinates
        thetaunit="degrees",
        mode='markers',
        marker=dict(
            color='peru'
        )
    )
]

layout = go.Layout(
    showlegend=True,
    polar=dict(
        domain=dict(  # set chart size and position
            x=[0, 0.8],
            y=[0.3, 0.8]),
        sector=[0, 1800],  # set chart shape (half or full)
        angularaxis=dict(
            thetaunit="degrees",
            dtick=10,
            rotation=90,
            direction='clockwise'),
        radialaxis=dict(
            range=[1, 8000])
    )
)

fig = go.Figure(data=trace, layout=layout)
offline.plot(fig)
```

These changes were sufficient to produce the following:

[image: Plotly Radial Plot]

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thank you, DatHydroGuy!
Changing `go.Layout sector=[0, 180] to sector=[-90, 90]` works for the angular axis range.
Changing `go.Scatterplot r=[y] to r=[int(a) for a in y]` and `go.Scatterplot theta=[x] to theta=[int(b) for b in x]` shows that there's data (without these changes it doesnt show anything), however it's not shown correctly (data points cluster along the radial axis).

Comment: How about if you change `r=[int(a) for a in y]` to `r=[float(a) for a in y]` and `theta=[int(b) for b in x]` to `theta=[float(b) for b in x]`?  Does that stop the clustering?

Comment: Thanks! No, changing "int to float" throws back the same plot, with clustered data points along the radial axis.

Comment: OK, one more thing to try:  Your `go.Layout()` states that the `angularaxis` `thetaunit` is `degrees`.  Make sure that your `Scatterpolar` has the same units by inserting the line `thetaunit='degrees',` inside your `go.Scatterpolar()`

Comment: I have updated my answer to include my full code.  If you compare it to your code, is there anything there which looks different (apart from my random data generation)?  Anything I'm doing which you're not, or vice versa?

Comment: except for the thetaunit="degrees" in go.Scatterpolar, which didn't result in any changes in my plot, it is the same. It is for some reason working now –yeah– please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much DatHydroGuy! I completely rewrote the code with your changes and it is working now. Below is the code and an image of the output. NOICE! Thanks again, HydroGuy, for you help!

If somebody knows how to rotate it (by 90° counterclockwise) and mirror it (-90 left, 0 top, 90 right) please let me know. I tried `rotation=` and `direction=` commands, but they did not work and collide with the `sector=` command for setting the angular axis range from -90 to 90.

Cheers, Ron

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly import plotly
import plotly.offline as offline
import numpy as np
import plotly


# data
x= np.genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=",", usecols=(0), skip_header=1, encoding = 'unicode_escape')
y= np.genfromtxt("data.csv", delimiter=",", usecols=(1), skip_header=1, encoding = 'unicode_escape')

trace = [
    go.Scatterpolar(
        r = [float(a) for a in y], #radial coordinates
        theta = [float(b) for b in x], #angular coordinates
        mode = 'lines',
        marker = dict(
            color = 'peru'
        )
    )
]

layout = go.Layout(
    showlegend = True,
    legend=dict(
        x=1),
    polar = dict(
        domain = dict( # set chart size and position 
        x = [0, 1],
        y = [0, 1]),
        sector = [-90,90],   # set chart shape (half or full)
        angularaxis = dict(
            thetaunit = "degrees",
            dtick = 10,
            #rotation = -90, #does not work
            #direction = "clockwise" # does not work
            ),
        radialaxis = dict(
            range = [1, 6500])

))


fig = go.Figure(data=trace, layout=layout)
offline.plot(fig)
```

[plotly half polar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG44Q.png)

Comment: Glad you've got it working!  To rotate the final output, you need to add `rotation=-90` into your `angularaxis` dictionary.  You also need to play with the `sector` values.  I updated them to `sector=[-180, 0]` to get everything to line up correctly.  I updated my original answer to reflect these changes.

Comment: Update: I updated the code to include the `direction` attribute inside the `angularaxis`.  This now has exactly the same orientation as your original screenshot.

Comment: ... my "data calling lines" (x=('data.csv.', delimiter=...)). I tried a few things, but didn't manage to get it run..